# How can I translate this piece of code from Erlang to Elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir, ejabberd

How can I translate this piece of code from Erlang to Elixir?

Erlang:

```
xmpp:get_text(Packet#message.body)
```

Elixir:

```
:xmpp.get_text(packet ... ?
```

Comment: An agent of Chaos brutally murders a puppy every time you translate a line of code from Erlang to Elixir. Please, for the puppies.

Comment: I am sorry for that. But I think doesn't make sense import a Elixir library to do the same job. Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the record field access syntax. That code accesses the field `body` of the term `Packet` assuming that the `Packet` is a `message` record. Elixir provides a Record module to deal with this. You need to first import the record's definition using `Record.extract` (change the `.hrl` path to point to the dependency's `hrl` file that includes the definition of the record; search for `-record(message` in the library you're using) and then use that definition. Here's an example:

```
defmodule A do
  Record.defrecord :message, Record.extract(:message, from_lib: "path/to/file.hrl")
end
```

Now `Packet#message.body` translates to `A.message(packet, :body)`.

Comment: Thanks @dogbert! just in case, I am using this library[1], I thought that library already did this.

1 - https://github.com/processone/xmpp

Comment: The library declares the record but you need to pull it into Elixir. The library does not include any Elixir module which does this. I found the `message` record declared in `xmpp/include/xmpp_codec.hrl`, so you'll likely want to pass `from_lib: "deps/xmpp/include/xmpp_codec.hrl"`.